# Shifters: which natural weapon is the primary one?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack, racial-traits, natural-weapon

Building a shifter character. Razorclaw, so they start with two claw attacks, both primary. Later, they take levels in Weretouched Master (wolverine) and get a bite attack as well. Is the bite also a primary weapon? That seems very unusual compared to monsters in the MM. Or is the bite secondary because it isn't explicitly primary?

Eventually it won't matter, once they take Improved Unarmed Strike and all the natural attacks become secondaries in the attack routine, but until then I need to know whether they're taking a -5 to some attacks.

Comment: I didn't realize how drastically this was changed between 3.5 and Pathfinder, and was about to answer entirely incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weretouched master ought to specify, but it doesn’t. There is no default.

But anyway, even if it *did* specify that the bite attack was primary, you can’t generally have more than 1 primary weapon (or 1 pair of primary weapons). If you get more, the additional ones are downgraded to secondary *anyway*.

> When a creature has more than one natural weapon, one of them (or sometimes a pair or set of them) is the primary weapon. All the creature’s remaining natural weapons are secondary.

<sup>([Natural Weapons special ability description](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#naturalWeapons))</sup>

So even if there’s a ruling that the weretouched I (*wolverine*) ability’s bite attack is a primary natural weapon, you’d be forced to choose whether your claws or your bite is the primary. If it’s not, then of course it must be secondary and your claws remain primary—which was probably the better option in the opposite case anyway.